# reading particular value from array of integers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I've `brandids=[1,2,3]` which is an array of integer.

How to get any 1 value at a time so that i can use that as a parameter in params one by one.

Comment: if you want only one value then just take it with its index position. if you want to get `1` use `brandids[0]`. otherwise use loops

Answer (score 0):

Use "shift" method, which will extract the first element of an array.

```
> param = brandids.shift
> param # => 1
> brandids # => [2, 3]
```

Does this anser your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
brandids.each do |brand_id|
    # Do something with a brand id
    puts "Provided brand ID : #{brand_id}" 
end
```

In your case this code should write

```
Provided brand ID : 1
Provided brand ID : 2
Provided brand ID : 3
```

Note that this code is 100% Ruby. This has nothing to do with any Rails specific method or behavior. For more info on Ruby arrays, please see : http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html